# How to get unique id for each div?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular 2, and I have a `div` that I'm repeating in my markup, with a `click` event on it. The code is as shown below:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addExtra">
        Add Extra</button>
    </div>

    <div *ngFor="let val of addExtra">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" id="title" style="width:100%" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The TypeScript code that the button is using is:

```
class MyClass {
    // Other things in my code...

    addExtra(): void {
        this.addExtra.push("inserted");
    }
}
```

How would one add a unique id for each `div` added, so that I can have a delete button to delete that `div`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `index` variable:

```
<div *ngFor="let val of addExtra let i=index" [id]="'id'+i">
```

but for a delete button you don't need the `id` property. You can use

```
<div *ngFor="let val of addExtra">
  <button (click)="delete(val)">delete</button>
```

or

```
<div *ngFor="let val of addExtra let i=index">
  <button (click)="delete(i)">delete</button>
```